# Is it possible to send a variable number of emails using SSRS subscription?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-subscription

I've only ever managed to setup a fixed number of SSRS subscriptions, each corresponding to 1 email, but now I want to be able to send out x emails with different contents, where x is a variable that can be queried out from the DB along with the corresponding content. The template across all these emails, however, needs to be the same.

For example: I can query the number of meetings scheduled for today - which will vary for different days - and then send out an email at the start of the day for each of those meetings, with the subject line as the title of the meeting and the email body or the 'report' showing the meeting agenda.

Is this something I can achieve using reporting services?

I was able to find a solution involving SSIS that allows one to send out emails to a variable number of recipients, but I was wondering if there's another way out:

Here's that solution if anyone's interested:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff793463

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It can be possible trough using SQL server also.

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale sorry, care to elaborate?

Comment: give sample table or query for your variable.

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale found the solution (below) but thanks for coming forth!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution and it's relatively simple. Under Step 3 of setting up the Data Driven Subscription where you specify a query, I wrote one that returns a list of recipients and content to be used by the report/email body. **SSRS automatically varies the number of emails sent out based on the number of records the query fetches.**